# Grep first word of a line from a file

Tags: grep, regular-expression

So I have a `file.txt` like

```
John john@gmail.com
Mary mary@gmail.com
```

but I also have

```
Pickethunter123 timmy@gmail.com
XPC61 roger@gmail.com
GeorgeBushSucks michael@gmail.com
```

and I have a list of English names `names.txt`. Is there a way to grep only by the first word of a line against another file?

Comment: What did you try?  Think of the anchor `^`.

Comment: If this is a followup to [your previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/659452/116858), where you had a JSON file, then it would be a lot easier (or at least convenient) to solve this while parsing that JSON file than doing it as a separate step afterwards.  Consider asking a question about your overall goal rather than separate questions about each tiny step that you _believe_ that you need to take.

Comment: Can you add an example of `names.txt` and the desired output?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a regular expression to match only at the start of a pattern, you can add the line anchor `^` to each line of your `names.txt` file. If you don't want to modify the file in place, you can do that on the fly with `sed` for example:

```
sed 's/^/^/' names.txt | grep -wf - file.txt
```

passing the result to `grep -f` via standard input `-`.

Alternatively, awk is a good option for delimited data:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{fn[$1]; next} $1 in fn' names.txt file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Connecting this to [your *previous* question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/659452/116858), where you had a JSON document with the contents

```json
{"a":"town, state, country","e":["john@company.com"],"n":"john smith"}
{"a":"town, state, country","e":["zac@company.com","zacsurname@gmail.com"],"n":"zac surname"}
{"a":"town, state, country","n":"jane doe"}
```

To pull out the list of 1st names (the value up to the first space character in each `n` key's value) together with the email addresses in `e` values, I proposed that you'd use `jq` and did

```bsh
jq -r '
    select(has("n") and has("e")) |
    (.n|split(" ")[0]) as $name |
    .e[] | [ $name, . ] | @tsv' file.txt
```

(see [my previous answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/659454/116858) for a brief explanation about this command).

We may modify this to also incorporate reading a list of valid names:

```bsh
jq -Rs 'rtrimstr("\n") | split("\n") | map(ascii_upcase)' names.txt |
jq -r '
    . as $valid_names |
    inputs | select(has("n") and has("e")) |
    (.n|split(" ")[0]) as $name | select(($name | ascii_upcase) == $valid_names[]) |
    .e[] | [ $name, . ] | @tsv' - file.txt
```

This calls `jq` twice.  The first invocation is to transform the `names.txt` list of names (assumed to be one single name per line) into a JSON array of upper-case strings.

For example, if our `names.txt` file contains

```
marty
zac
```

then the first `jq` invocation would produce the JSON document

```json
[
  "MARTY",
  "ZAC"
]
```

The second `jq` invocation starts by reading from the first one, creating the set `$valid_names` from the list of upper-case names.

The `inputs` function is then used to read the JSON objects from `file.txt`, one by one, and the rest is pretty much like it was in my previous answer to you, only we restrict the data via an extra `select` to only be those entries with 1st names that matches a name in the `$valid_names` set.

With the `names.txt` file as in my example above, and with `file.txt` as at the top of this answer, the output would be the single line

```
zac     zac@company.com
zac     zacsurname@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You can transform the file with `cut`, then pipe that into your `grep` command:

```bsh
cut -d' ' -f1 file.txt | grep -F -f names.txt
```